# How to GROUP BY a column/s in data studio

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, looker-studio

I have a sales table with the purchase history of multiple customers. Needless to say a single customer can appear multiple times in the table. I need to  group by the customers and do a count of the industries each customer works in and visualize it in a table in data studio. I need to do all of this in data studio itself.

In big query the syntax would look something like this:

```
SELECT Industry, count(industry) AS industry_count 
FROM (SELECT 
    CustomerID, 
    Industry 
    FROM `project1.pr.df_full` 
    WHERE  segment = 'Lost'
    GROUP BY CustomerID, Industry)
GROUP BY Industry
ORDER BY industry_count DESC
```

How can I achieve the same thing in data studio? The `WHERE` clause doesn't have to be there because I have a segment filter on the page I'm trying to do this on

Comment: Did you try using your query in DataStudio? I reproduced your query and it seems ok. If you tried, what is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in the comment, I reproduced your query and it worked fine.
[Here](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6370296?hl=en) you can see a guide about how to connect `BigQuery` to `DataStudio`

Please, notice that DataStudio have some limitations in the query syntax:

[image]

If you need further information, please let me know

Answer (score 0):

You could query the raw data, and make calculations on Data Studio side. Be sure to use the field you need to group by as **dimension**.

```
SELECT 
    CustomerID, 
    Industry,
    segment
    FROM `project1.pr.df_full`
```

Then in a Data Studio table use "Industry" field as **dimension**, and "CustomerId" field as **metric**, using Count as the aggregation for the metric. As you also have a "segment" field in your data source, filtering by this field will not be a problem.

I hope this help!

Answer (score -2):

I'm wondering why you don't write the query as:

```
SELECT CustomerID, COUNT(DISTINCT Industry) as industry_count
FROM `project1.pr.df_full` 
WHERE  segment = 'Lost'
GROUP BY CustomerID
ORDER BY industry_count DESC;
```